# Invalid Resource ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I keep getting this error since yesterday when using the sandbox:

{"response":{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"26f3ac4fc5738","httpStatusCode":404},"httpStatusCode":404}
ERROR: UserModel::makePayPalPayment::paypal.payment.execute: Error: Response Status : 404

And today I am getting this error:

Error loading: https://www.xxxx.com/api/pay?paymentId=PAY-8SE27150X9535431TK7PDQJA&token=EC-6GU51565SC426212J&PayerID=HQV9ASU3RRW5S, Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe6ac6d5320 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.xxxx.com/api/pay?paymentId=PAY-8SE27150X9535431TK7PDQJA&token=EC-6GU51565SC426212J&PayerID=HQV9ASU3RRW5S, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.xxxx.com/api/pay?paymentId=PAY-8SE27150X9535431TK7PDQJA&token=EC-6GU51565SC426212J&PayerID=HQV9ASU3RRW5S, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.xxxx.com/api/pay?paymentId=PAY-8SE27150X9535431TK7PDQJA&token=EC-6GU51565SC426212J&PayerID=HQV9ASU3RRW5S, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.xxxx.com/api/pay?paymentId=PAY-8SE27150X9535431TK7PDQJA&token=EC-6GU51565SC426212J&PayerID=HQV9ASU3RRW5S, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

Is there an issue with the sandbox?

Comment: Have you passed all necessary information?